# Click TextBlock to open Expander object WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, contextmenu

I'm not so good at XAML, and I'm trying to make something like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [deviantart.net](http://fc04.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2013/275/c/2/accordion_by_psdchat-d6oz0b5.jpg))</sub>

I want a few options (The orange ones) and then when I click the orange ones, they expand and show further options.

Here's the little code I have:

```
<ListView Background="#585858" Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <ListViewItem>
        <Grid Margin="15,5">
            <TextBlock Foreground="#FFABADB3" Text="MenuTitle" FontSize="20" Grid.Row="0"/>
            <Expander Grid.Row="1">
            </Expander>
        </Grid>
    </ListViewItem>
</ListView>
```

But it doesn't really work as I want it to. The Textblock and the Expander goes on the same line.

Here's what my code looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ph9th.png

If anyone can guide me in the right direction I'd be really glad!
Thanks in advance and happy holidays :)

Comment: a `ListView` is not appropiate for this. Use a `ListBox`.

Comment: Please post your XAML as part of the question instead of linking to a `jpeg` of it.

Comment: Okey, I will try to use a Listbox instead. And, I did post the code? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the TextBlock in the Expander `Header`

```
<ListView Background="#585858" Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
 <ListViewItem>
   <Grid Margin="15,5">
     <Expander Grid.Row="1">
      <Expander.Header>
        <TextBlock Foreground="#FFABADB3" Text="MenuTitle" FontSize="20" Grid.Row="0"/>
      </Expander.Header>   
     </Expander>
   </Grid>
 </ListViewItem>
</ListView>
```

But if you want the design from the picture,you will have a lot more work to do. You will need to "retemplate" the `ListViewItem` and the `Expander`. Default templates are far from the one on the picture.